# Number Of Cycles in a Even Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I was trying to prove following problem for Bondy Murthy Graph Theory Book

The problem is :

> 5.2.12 a) By employing the splitting-off operation, show that every even graph has an odd number of cycle decompositions.

as we knew :

> A Graph assumed as a Even graph iff the degree of its each vertex
> would be even
>
> Splitting-off a pair of edges $( xu, xv )$ means deleting these two
> edges and adding a new edge $uv$   if  $u \ne v$

assuming the above definition, after doing `splitting-off` process on each cycle we will have only one edge, for example assume a cycle in graph, it is like a circle, each time we do `splitting-off` we are decreasing the number of edges by `1`, and finally we would have only an edge

my main question is how can i prove that the number of such lines(=converted cycles by splitting-off method) is odd ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?